# Tinymce 500 ошибка

Tags: изображения, tinymce

Помогите, пожалуйста. Когда выбираю добавить картинку через редактор `tinymce`, мне в консоли выводится 500 ошибка, а в поп-апе вечно крутится колесико... Как можно исправить?

Comment: Пути к папке для загрузок изображений указаны правильно? Проверьте.

Comment: да правильно, проверял.просто вчера работало, а почему могло отпасть понятия не имею. а имеет значение как была создана папка, через редактор или ftp?

Comment: вот сама ошибка

POST http://www.originalam.net/admin/js/tiny_mce/plugins/images/connector/php/ 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.3.2.js:3633

Comment: Проверьте права на доступ в папку.